# Object does not support property or method Following the 'Cookie'

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code in my index.php. In Mozilla its ok. But in Ie i got an error.

I need a litle help to fix this.

The user fill the form in SITEB.php and after send and successfull i redirect to index.php, clear all my variable, cookies, etc...to avoid to send again, or access information..blabla...

The part of the code is the following, where the error is:

Source code:

```
<?php if (isset($_SESSION['mail_succ'])) { echo "<div id='msg_succ'>";  echo 'Sucess, contact you soon...'; echo "</div>"; unset($_SESSION['mail_succ']);session_destroy();echo "<script type='text/javascript'>    $.cookie('chiteltip', null);     $.cookie('hitel', '8');     $.cookie('hiteltip', '8');     $.cookie('teher', '8'); $.cookie('teherm2', '8');  $.cookie('ingatlan', '8'); </script>";}?>
```

View the source after redirect:

```
 <div id='msg_succ'>Sucess, contact you soon...</div><script type='text/javascript'>    $.cookie('chiteltip', null);     $.cookie('hitel', '8');     $.cookie('hiteltip', '8');     $.cookie('teher', '8'); $.cookie('teherm2', '8');  $.cookie('ingatlan', '8'); </script>
```

Thank you for the help

Comment: Have you loaded the `jQuery.cookie` plugin?

Comment: Yes.. How would you prepare a dish without a pan?

Comment: Are you asking if its necessary to load the library you are trying to call? As a general rule, yes. http://archive.plugins.jquery.com/project/Cookie

Comment: Dutch: I dont really understand. In mozilla works well, no error. So why is it so necessary?

Comment: Sorry. I check again. Yes. Cookie plugin loaded. (just copied into an other JS file..)

Comment: What's the actual error you're getting in IE?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than doing `$.cookie('xyz',null)`...do `setcookie('xyz',time()-3600)`

Comment: The problem is related to JavaSript, not PHP.